# Create new column in select with regex in sql

Tags: sql, regex, select

I have a column in sql table as below:

```
ColumnName
yahoo.com/news/usa/today
cnn.com/
espn.com/nfl
msn.com/en-us/
```

Now I want to create a new column in the select statement that includes only the domain and the section after the first slash only, like this:

```
NewColumn
yahoo.com/news
espn.com/nfl
msn.com/en-us
```

My concern is not about the regex, but rather how to use it in the select statement, something like this:

```
SELECT (*substring ColumnName values*) as NewColumn
FROM table
WHERE ColumnName  LIKE [regex]
```

What to write in place of *substring ColumnName values* ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (regex functionality tends to differ between the products.)

Comment: It's not mentioned actually :/ I'm writing it on paper ..

Answer (score 0):

if ure using oracle then this will work for u

```
select case when  instr(columnName,'/',1,2) = 0 then columnName
        else substr( columnName,1, instr(columnName,'/',1,2)-1 ) end Newcolumn 
from mytable
 WHERE ColumnName  LIKE '%/%' escape '_/' ;
```